# How to put large text data (~20mb) into sql cs 3.5 database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-ce

I am using following query to insert some large text data :

```
internal static string InsertStorageItem =
            "insert into Storage(FolderName, MessageId, MessageDate, StorageData) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', @StorageData)";
```

and the code I am using to execute this query is as follows :

```
string content = "very very large data";
string query = string.Format(InsertStorageItem, "Inbox", "AXOGTRR1445/DSDS587444WEE", "4/19/2010 11:11:03 AM");
var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, _sqlConnection);
var paramData = command.Parameters.Add("@StorageData", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText);
paramData.Value = content;
paramData.SourceColumn = "StorageData";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But at the last line I am getting this following error :

```
 System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException was unhandled by user code
Message=The data was truncated while converting from one data type to another. [ Name of function(if known) =  ]
Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
HResult=-2147467259
NativeError=25920
StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Chithi.Client.Exchange.ExchangeClient.SaveItem(Item item, Folder parentFolder)
       at Chithi.Client.Exchange.ExchangeClient.DownloadNewMails(Folder folder)
       at Chithi.Client.Exchange.ExchangeClient.SynchronizeParentChildFolder(WellKnownFolder wellknownFolder, Folder parentFolder)
       at Chithi.Client.Exchange.ExchangeClient.SynchronizeFolders()
       at Chithi.Client.Exchange.ExchangeClient.WorkerThreadDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
InnerException:
```

Now my question is how am I supposed to insert such large data to sqlce db?

Regards,

Anindya Chatterjee

http://abstractclass.org

Comment: How is the StorageData field defined?

Comment: The db data type of StorageData in db is ntext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the docs for ntext data type?

> Variable-length Unicode data with a
>   maximum length of 230 - 1
>   (1,073,741,823) characters. Storage
>   size, in bytes, is two times the
>   number of characters entered

Is your very large content greater in size than the maximum? If so you're out of luck - you need a data type which can store more data than ntext. My suggestion: varbinary(MAX) or Image.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should think about why do you have to put such large amounts of text into a database. Maybe a reference (link - path) to an external file would be a better solution.

Comment: Why I went for this is because I am creating a desktop mail storage, so creating files for each message would be really tedious, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The code you listed ought to work. Have you checked your bases first?

I'm thinking it could be one of the other columns that throws the exception. In order of likelihood:

1. MessageDate
2. MessageId
3. FolderName

So, first test it with StorageData=NULL or a small text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What a drama!! You are right, I was keep thinking that the StorageData is creating problem as it is large. The actual culprit is MessageId it is also a long string and there only it is failing cause I made it nvarchar(100) only.

Thanks again, for this pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest specifying the length of the field when creating the parameter:

```
var paramData = command.Parameters.Add("@StorageData", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText, /* column length here */);
paramData.Value = content;
```

Comment: No it still throwing the exception. I used content.Length as the size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me tell you one thing that I am going to create a desktop mail storage. Still I am not sure how to store the messages in an elegant way. This was my first try to store the content of the message in sqlce db. Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: It's advisable to add all the parameters in this manner, and specify the lengths as the column sizes in the actual database - this may make it easier to spot in the debugger as well, as you could compare the actual string.Length vs. what the database is defined as.

Answer (score 0):

I if you can change the type of `StorageData` from `ntext` to `image` and write your content as Binary. I guess that would help you.

Cheers
AK